# Name for a function whose effect is canceled by another function?

Tags: functions, terminology

I've been saying function $f$ "*eclipses*" $g$ if $f(g(x)) = f(x)$ for all $x$.  For example, if $f(x) = \lvert x \rvert$ and $g(x) = -x$, then $f$ eclipses $g$.

Is there an established word for this property?

Comment: Don't know that there is one.  "Eclipse" is as good a candidate for a name as any....

Comment: This is loosely related to the concept of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coequalizer, so maybe one could call $f$ "co-equalizing $g$ and the identity"

Answer (score 15):

I would express this as "$f$ is invariant under $g$" or "$f$ is $g$-invariant", because of the analogy with group actions:

Compare this with: If $G$ is a group acting linearly on a vector space $V$, it induces an action on the dual $V^*$ by letting $g*f = f \circ g$. If $g*f = f$ for all $g \in G$, we would say $f$ is $G$-invariant.

Now, if $f : X \to Y$ and $g : X \to X$, then $g$ determines a monoid action of $\mathbb N$ on $X$ by letting $n$ act by $g_n = g \circ \cdots \circ g$. The monoid action induces a monoid action on the set of functions $X \to Y$, by letting $n*f = f \circ g_n$. A function $f$ is invariant under this monoid action iff $f \circ g = f$.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the answer.  I understood the first paragraph; the rest are sure to be valuable for people smarter than I.